# Adding a span class to a dynamic button

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a section of code within my application that displays button(s) when applicable, however, at the moment this simply shows the button with the text that has been passed through to it.

I need to add a glyph, which typically I would of done using a span class, however I'm clearly struggling to get the syntax right for this example!

My button looks like this:

```
<div class="pull-right" ng-show="!viewModel[0].projectCompleted && groupedProduct.products.length > 0">
 <div workflow-button project-element="getProjectElementById(groupedProduct.products[0].projectElementId)"></div>
</div>
```

The span to add would be: `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>`

I'm sure it's a daft thing I'm missing, but would appreciate any support you can provide!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to make your question more clear to solve

Answer (score 0):

```
<span ng-show='isapplicable'>I'm sure it's a daft thing I'm missing, but would appreciate any support you can provide!</span>
```

set the variable ***isapplicable*** value when its applicable

Comment: Hello - where abouts in my code snippet would I put that span?

Comment: where ever you want to display that span you can put that code and set the variable accordingly